# Xcode 6 Beta7 NSDictionary to Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Among the deluge of errors I got from updating to Beta 7 I got this particular one that makes me head-scratching ...

```
        let views:NSDictionary =
        [
            "leftView": _leftVC.view,
            "rightView": _rightVC.view,
            "outerView": _scrollView.superview
        ];
```

Error:
Cannot convert the expression't type 'Dictionary' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'
The method that needs 'views' needs an NSDictionary so I can't just use a Swift Dictionary.

How would I adapt the above code to satisfy Xcode6 Beta7?

Comment: Did you try setting `views` first, and then when you call the method, casting `views` to NSDictionary? I believe that's what Apple was saying in some of its workarounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `UIScrollView.superview` is an optional, so you have to put the unwrapped value in the dictionary

```
let views:NSDictionary =
[
    "leftView": _leftVC.view,
    "rightView": _rightVC.view,
    "outerView": _scrollView.superview!
];
```

Use a safer logic instead of an implicitly unwrapped (i.e. check that `superview` is not nil), unless you are 100% sure it contains a non nil value.

Even if the `views` variable is of `NSDictionary` type, the dictionary literal you are using to initialize it evaluates to a swift dictionary -  it is then silently bridged to a `NSDictionary`.

The reason why the compiler complains is that being `_scrollView.superview` an optional, it can potentially be nil, and that's not allowed.

As noted by @JackLawrance, a dictionary can have non uniform value types even when initialized with literals.

Sidenote: when will we get more meaningful error messages? :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what the problem was!

Comment: A dictionary literal that is used to construct an `NSDictionary` does not need uniform types. In addition, in all cases a dictionary literal does not require uniform types as long as the types have a common super type. For example, the type of this literal is `[String: UIView?]`. What's actually happening here is Swift is trying to prevent you from accidentally placing `nil` in an `NSDictionary`, which is a common pitfall in Objective-C that will result in a runtime crash because `NSDictionary` cannot contain `nil`. The error message is pretty bad though.