# How to put an UIImage into AnyObject Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

In Xcode 6 beta 7 I'm not able to put an UIImage in AnyObject Array:

```
var objects = [pizzaImage.image, title, ingredients.text]
```

error:
`Cannot convert the expression's type 'Array' to type 'ArrayLiteralConvertible`'

no problems in beta 6

**EDIT**
this is the complete code, tried everything, but stil no luck:

```
var objects = [pizzaImage.image!, title, ingredients.text!]]
var act = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objects, applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(act, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Is it related to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649875/xcode-6-beta7-nsdictionary-to-swift

Comment: unwrap the image have no effect in this case, sorry

Comment: @MarcelloCat: `ingredients.text` has to be unwrapped as well.

Comment: I tried everything, even the impossible!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
var objects = [pizzaImage.image!, title!, ingredients.text]]
var act = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objects, applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(act, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but if you put in only the title and the textField the complier has nothing to complain:

```
var objects = [title, ingredients.text]
```

why??
this is truly unclear...