# Why can you not initialize an empty Array in Swift?

Tags: swift

This code works,

```
let people = ["Tom","Dick","Harry"]
```

but this code doesn't work, for no apparent reason

```
let people = []
```

and nor does this (mutability matters not):

```
var people = []
```

The error is "Cannot convert expression's type Array to type 'ArrayLiteralConvertible'", but that makes no sense to me, and [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094018/unable-to-create-array-of-skactions) of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653462/how-to-put-an-uiimage-into-anyobject-array) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236492/storing-different-types-of-value-in-array-in-swift/24236512#24236512) that show up in a search address this question.

At first I thought it had to do with type inference, but that proves not to be the issue (at least not simply that!) since although this works (with type specified)

```
var people:Array = [""]
```

this does not (with type specified as above but no String given inside the Array):

```
var people:Array = []
```

Since the last of these two has the type specified explicitly, it shouldn't need a String passed inside the Array.

Some languages (weirdly!) consider the type of the variable to refer to the type of item ***inside*** the array, so I also tried specifying `String` instead of `Array`, but got the same results.  This first one works and the second doesn't:

```
var people:String = [""]
```

```
var people:String = []
```

Comment: Type inference requires enough context to infer from.

Comment: This *does* have to do with type interference - the key is that it has more to do with the type that the array *contains*, than it does with what type your `people` variable is. The compiler *knows* it's an `Array`. But the question is: An `Array` of *what*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is

```
let people : [String] = []
```

or

```
let people = [String]()
```

in both case, you can substitute `[String]` with `Array<String>`

For this code

```
let people = []
```

It is impossible for compiler to figure it out the type of `people`. What type do you expect it have?

Note `Array` is not a complete type because it require the generic part. A complete type is like `Array<String>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
let blankArray = [String]()
```

or ny other type you need.